# Rails content_for equivalent in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to use something like `content_for` from Rails in Javascript using node.js?
I have searched but didn't find anything so far.

Comment: Node.js is an evented, non-blocking I/O runtime for JavaScript; as such, that runtime itself would likely not have high-level functionality for storing and retrieving HTML markup blocks.  Consider searching for HTML templating libraries for frameworks such as [express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: I use express, through `sails.js`. But I never saw how to do so with these frameworks. Did I miss something?

Comment: Not sure - you should update your question to mention those frameworks specifically since they might have functionality similar to Rails' `content_for`.  Asking about "node.js" is too generic.

Comment: It's been a while I have asked that question and now understand how silly it was. Node.js being a backend framework and not a frontend framework, it will never incorportate such feature. Front end frameworks may, though. Like angular has its `ng-view` which can be used as the Rails `content_for` with named views defined and changing depending on the route. That's just an example.